# disk or partition log history

Tags: disk, logs

Is there any way to find the disk status log or disk free space history.

How can I show the disk status of my partition table?

Scenario is I have to provide the status of the disk status which is consumed "x" amount GB in just 12 hrs.

now the team says its not possible and asking me for log or proof.

Comment: You can start with `/var/log/messages` to see what application makes a lot of noise/has a lot of activity. Unless you tell us what you're running on that box, it will be pretty hard to have a clue about what's up.

Comment: It's a Oracle DB, it was `32 GB` yesterday which got increased to `4.8 TB`.   I know it was log, but then how can I show them the previous disk space.

Comment: Oracle team was able to delete/clean the log to normal, but then I have to show them something and get rid of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you like it simple you can use the `df` command via cron and wrote the output to a text file.

```
df -Th /path/to/mountpoint | tail -n1 >> /path/to/log/file
```

So you get a simple Text file and you can use it to create a report.

If you want wider monitoring I'll suggest to setup a monitoring system like zabbix or nagios.

Comment: Ahh, this is a great solution for the future, but my question is something different. which is related to past.

Comment: You answer doesn't fulfill the question requirement.

Comment: create reports of historical data is only possible if you collected these data before. If there are no data you can't create such a report. So my answer doesn't answer the question at all but give an outlook of what he can do to create such reports in furture.